# jquery if click is on element, do this, else do that

Tags: jquery, if-statement

This is confusing me now. Here is the pseudo code for what im trying to acheive, i need to use click as that hooks with the touch gestures im building with.

```
if body is clicked {
    if click has touched .circle {
        remove circle;
    }
    else {
        create circle;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**: Since writing the answer below, `delegate` has been superseded by [`on`](http://api.jquery.com/on/), which should be used instead.

---

You can (ab)use the [event bubbling](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html) that occurs. You attach the click listener to every div with a class `circle` that will ever be made (that can using jQuery's [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method), and once you're done dealing with that event, cancel the bubbling, so it won't reach the body click listener.

And, on the body listener, just append the circle.

Something like this:

```
var circle = $("<div>").addClass("circle").text("Circle!");

$("body").click(function() {
    $(this).append(circle);
});

$("body").delegate(".circle", "click", function(e) {
    $(this).remove();

    //To stop the bubbling up
    e.stopPropagation();
    return false;
});
```

Or, a simpler approach, simply check the target of the click event using `event.target`:

```
var circle = $("<div>").addClass("circle").text("Circle!");

$("body").click(function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);

    if (target.hasClass("circle")) {
        target.remove();
    }
    else {
        $(this).append(circle);
    }
});
```

Note: Because I created the `circle` div as a variable, there could only be one. If you don't want that, you can use [jQuery.fn.clone](http://api.jquery.com/clone/), or just make what you need on the spot.

Comment: Thanks for this, i forgot to mention i already had the create and remove function built, i just couldnt get the e.target to work, as i havent heard of it until now, so thanks the e.target is what ive been looking for to use!!

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(this).click(function (e) {
            var element = $(e.target);
            // do your job with element, for example you can retrieve its "id"
            alert(element.attr("id"));
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to use the `target` property of the event.

```
$('body').click(function (e) {
    if(e.target.hasClass("circle")) {
        $(e.target).remove();
    } else {
        // Create circle
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not respond exactly to your request, but it will give you ideas.

I would like this for many reasons (easier to code, ergonomically efficient, etc): [with a fake button](http://jsfiddle.net/3pNAX/).

Also, you can do droppable areas to create and delete items ( http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Droppable ).

Comment: ooh thats v nice thanks, but the idea is it needs to be anywhere on the page which is why ive used html as the selector now as its for a touch surface using absolute positioning.

Comment: Glad others have been able help you. :)